# Преобразование строки 'DataBaseTable' в 'data_base_table' (PHP)

Tags: php, строки, преобразование

Кто-нибудь подскажет, есть ли в PHP готовая функция, которая может преобразовать строку типа 'DataBaseTable' в 'data_base_table'?

Или может кто-то уже решал подобную проблему, написав собственную функцию?

Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: Я бы воспользовался функцией `preg_replace_callback`. В своём проекте делал обратное вашей задаче

Comment: `mb_strtolower(trim(preg_replace("/([A-Z])/", '_$1', $str), "_"))` какой-нибудь

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем, кто откликнулся!

Реализовал вот так:

```
public function getEntityTableName($className) {
    $resStr = preg_replace_callback('/[A-Z][a-z]*/', 
        function ($param) {return '_' . $param[0];}, $className);
    return substr_replace(strtolower($resStr), '', 0, 1);
}
```

Определение имени таблицы (нижний регистр с разделителем '_') по имени класса для хранения его екземпляров.